# How do I access superclass properties in a Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism, criteria, superclass, joined-subclass

I'm using basic table-per-class polymorphism in Hibernate. So I have:

```
<class name="SuperClass" table="SUPER">
    <id name="anId" type="long">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <properties name="uniqueFields" unique="true">
        <property name="one" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="two" not-null="true"/>
    </properties>

    <joined-subclass name="SubClass1" table="SUB1">
        <key column="anId"/>
        <property name="other"/>
    </joined-subclass>

    <joined-subclass name="SubClass2" table="SUB2">
        ...
    </joined-subclass>

    ...

</class>
```

So, basically I have a bunch of subclasses, each of which is holding some subclass specific data. I have a key, but I also need a compound unique constraint on a couple of other properties.

If a create a criteria:

```
 createCriteria(SubClass1.class).add(Restrictions.eq("one", "VALUE")).list()
```

I get a stack dump caused by: *Invalid column name 'one'*.

If I create the criteria based on SuperClass.class it works, but a need to add restrictions that apply to both the superclass and the subclass (and this code is actually buried under a whole lot of other stuff).

I can get to the key, but it is declared in both places. Can I not access the global properties from the subclass in a criteria? Do I need to declare them somehow? Or some type of cast?

Comment: what happens if you remove `<properties name="uniqueFields" unique="true">`?

Comment: Not sure, but that constraint is very important. Normally if I create a criteria on the subclass, should I be able to access elements of the super ?

Comment: AFAIK yes, it should be possible, however i am only certain for NHibernate but it is very close to Hibernate